# After setting up the Jekyll serve and the website directory properly.It shows not found when I try to search localhost:4000

Tags: jekyll

[After setting up the Jekyll serve.It shows "/" is not found.How can I make the motification afterwards?[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVTgA.jpg)

Comment: Can you paste your code instead of linking to images. Please.

Answer (score 1):

You blog is served at `http://127.0.0.1:400/blog/` not at `http://127.0.0.1:400/`. This is because you've set `baseurl: /blog`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in config:

```
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 4000
baseurl: ""
```

But if you need to have your site in /blog directory:

```
baseurl: "/blog/"
destination: "/your/path/to/your/blog/blog"
```